# Arm Exception handling mechanics

Tags: arm

Was going through basics of arm exception handling, and come to this doubt:
(I am taking example of abort exception)
Lets assume processor is running in user mode.

When an *exception* happens the processor will save the current `pc` to abort_mode `LR` and `CPSR` to abort mode `SPSR` and the execution jumps to vector address for the abort, so `PC` will now contain the *vector address* for the abort.

So what I get here is before transferring the flow to abort mode(having pc to abort vector).
   CPU will perform below task:
  "Current `pc` to abort_mode `LR` and `CPSR` to abort mode `SPSR` and then **execution jumps to vector address** for the abort," as mentioned above.
In which mode and from where instructions are executed to perform above task?

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: @tangrs, Please see if you get me now.

Comment: The *microcode* inside the ARM does all this.  **Note:** the vector table in the ARM is `code`, not pointers to `code`.  Typically some sort of branch or `ldr pc, =abort_handler` is in the vector table.  There is a small *hole* for the data abort and two instructions are available.  The FIQ is at the end and doesn't have to jump.

Answer (score 3):

When an *abort* exception happens, the text you are quoting is correct. Other exceptions use different modes.

The copying of PC to the exception mode LR and the CPSR to SPSR and setting the PC to the exception vector is what the processor does for you automatically on taking the exception. There are no instructions required. It also switches to the SP used by that exception mode.

The exception handler is what comes next. and is completely in software.